# jQuery select checkbox by clicking parent div

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

Here is what I want to happen: when I click on the checkbox in the `imageContainer` div, the checkbox should show checked. I also add some classes to change the background color and label color of selected boxes. This part is working.

I am able to click the `imageContainer` div and the checkbox inside that div is checkmarked. But when I click the checkbox directly, it does not show the checkmark in the box. I have tried `preventDefault`, `return false` and `stopPropagation` but no luck.

```
     <div class="imageContainer" id="question-container-7571">
        <img src="/rfs/servicerequest/taskImages/flooring_kitchen.jpg" alt="Flooring">
        <div class="l-top-space">
           <label for="id_7571_11491">Flooring</label>
           <div class="l-right"><input id="id_7571_11491" type="checkbox" name="7571" value="11491"></div>
           <input id="id_7571_11492" type="hidden" name="7571" value="11492">
        </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the jQuery I am using:

```
  jQuery('.imageContainer').toggle(
     function(e) {
        var imgCont = jQuery(this);
        imgCont.find('input').prop('checked', true);
        imgCont.addClass('ic-checked');
        imgCont.find('label').addClass('ic-selected');
     },
     function(e) {
        var imgCont = jQuery(this);
        imgCont.find('input').prop('checked', false);
        imgCont.removeClass('ic-checked');
        imgCont.find('label').removeClass('ic-selected');
     }
  );
```

Any help or tips on what I am missing would be great!

Comment: Sorry not to have an answer for you, but I will just give you two thoughts: 1. I suspect you can't do this with that `toggle` feature, and 2. You don't want to anyway, it's gone from the latest version of jQuery. :-)

Comment: A solution could be to place the `<input type="checkbox"...` outside the `div` you want to click, and then position it absolute on the right spot. For this you might want a wrapper div.

Comment: Why do you use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) at all? You want a click event reaction, right?

Comment: I was trying using 2 different versions of code...one using toggle, and one using change. The code using toggle seemed to have more of the functionality I needed. Using Change, I wasn't getting everything I needed to happen. But, the more I have researched today, the more I have learned, such as toggle being deprecated and such. So, I am working on eliminating toggle and rewriting the code with Click or Change.

Comment: @Steeven: There used to be a version of `toggle` that hooked up two event handlers (one for every other click); details: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ It was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it has taken me so long to get back. Here is the code I ended up with and it works as I need it to. Click on surrounding div, label, or checkbox and select the check box and change the background of the surrounding div.

```
jQuery('.imageContainer input:checkbox,.imageContainer label').bind("click",function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
   jQuery("div.imageContainer input:checkbox").bind("click",function(){
      var imageContainerDiv = jQuery(this).closest("div.imageContainer");
      var imageContainerInput = jQuery(this);
      var triggerEl="";
      imageContainer(imageContainerDiv,triggerEl);
   });
   jQuery("div.imageContainer").bind("click",function(){
      var imageContainerDiv = jQuery(this);
      var triggerEl=imageContainerDiv;
      imageContainer(imageContainerDiv,triggerEl);
   });
   function imageContainer(imageContainerDiv,triggerElement){
      var imageContainer=jQuery(imageContainerDiv).children("input:checkbox");
      var imageCheckbox = jQuery(imageContainerDiv).find("input");
      if(triggerElement==imageContainerDiv){
         imageCheckbox.prop("checked", !imageCheckbox.prop("checked"));
      }
      jQuery(imageContainerDiv).toggleClass("ic-checked");
      jQuery(imageContainerDiv).find("label").toggleClass("ic-selected");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because, your click is propagated from the checkbox to the container so the checkbox will get immediately unchecked and rechecked.  You can add the following binding to prevent that:

```
jQuery('input:checkbox', '.imageContainer').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

but it will not trigger the css changes in your container, so I would change your code to:

```
function handleCheckbox(imgCont, checkbox, toggle) {
      var checked = checkbox.prop("checked");
      if (toggle)
      {
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checked);
        checked = !checked;
      }
      if (checked)
      {
        imgCont.addClass('ic-checked');
        imgCont.find('label').addClass('ic-selected');
      }
      else
      {
        imgCont.removeClass('ic-checked');
        imgCont.find('label').removeClass('ic-selected');
      }
}
jQuery('.imageContainer').click(function(e){
   var eventInitiator = jQuery(e.target);
   if (eventInitiator.is(":checkbox") || eventInitiator.is("label"))
      return;
   var imgCont = jQuery(this);
   handleCheckbox(imgCont, imgCont.find('input:checkbox'), true);
});
jQuery('input:checkbox', '.imageContainer').change(function(e){
   var checkbox = jQuery(this);
   handleCheckbox(checkbox.closest(".imageContainer"), checkbox, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery rewrite (the very first line is only needed, if some checkboxes might be checked at pageload):

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SteevenSpangsdorf/dTAgf/).

```
/*On page run*/
jQuery('.imageContainer input:checked').addClass("ic-checked");

/*On click*/
jQuery('.imageContainer').click(function(){

  var imgCont = jQuery(this);

  if(imgCont.is('.ic-checked')) {
    imgCont.find('input').prop('checked', false);
    imgCont.removeClass('ic-checked');
    imgCont.find('label').removeClass('ic-selected');

  } else {

    imgCont.find('input').prop('checked', true);
    imgCont.addClass('ic-checked');
    imgCont.find('label').addClass('ic-selected');

  }

});
```

Instead of using `toogle`, which seems a bit misused here, I simply added a click event handler.

The most important point here is that I don't check if the checkbox is checked. Doing that, the same problem would occour (since when you click the checkbox, it is checked, and THEN the jQuery runs and finds it checked and therefore unchecks it again). Instead I check if a your added class is present, which you only add when onCheck.

Since you already do this addClass in your code, this can be reused and no further classes are added.

Comment: @galloe71: Why did you accept this answer? It doesn't work. Clicking the div does not set the checkbox (or add the class). The second part of that is easier to see if we make the class do something: http://jsfiddle.net/dTAgf/1/

Comment: Works in Chrome. Haven't tested elsewhere.

Comment: @ steeven: I'm using Chrome, and it isn't working. It works if you click the checkbox, but not if you click the word "Flooring." (E.g., the converse of the problem the OP was having.) Still, though, the OP is the ultimate arbiter, of course, and he/she seems happy. :-)